# non English Url not working in Php

Tags: php, web-services, xampp

I'm getting data of post  by ID /78/ as in Url and i'm printing the post title in the Parameter[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD7sz.png) which is in urdu Language php sys OBJECT NOT FOUND

```
http://localhost/newscafe.pk/news-show/78/some-non-English-word
```

[image]

**and When i remove that Non-english url It Fetched tha data**

Comment: Well, how should we know what your implemented logic does with such a request?

Comment: using urlencode() would be a good start

Comment: there are some news  on that news posts url is "website name/show-post-page/id of post /title of post" and i'm using the post id from parameter 1 of the url  and get data from the sql  title of post  after the id is used for SEO

Comment: i have used that Urlencode() still same error